# Data path in logic circuit

Tags: timing-analysis, sample-and-hold

In the fig below is the path from CLK of 1st FF to Output(DataOut1) a valid data path. If so why is it not shown? Is it because its just the combination of PATH2 and PATH3?

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: Depends on your definition of "data path", I think.  The clock input of a flip-flop causes a transfer of data from the "D" input to the "Q" output.

Comment: The start points of a Data path are CLK and Input port and the End points of Data Path are D pin of Flop and Output port. So why not a path from CLK of 1st FF to Dataout?

Comment: As I said, it depends on your definition of "Data path" - go back to whereever you found this diagram, and see what they have to say about it.